# Is there a way to manage browser [chrome] session cookies with a fast toggle for multiple users?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, user-profiles, cookies

I feel I should go into more detail.  My wife and I share a laptop and browse email.  Currently we keep coming back to each others gmail accounts, having to log out and log back in.  Are there any good extensions or addons that would allow us to toggle back and forth between these?  This does not necessarily need to apply to just gmail but include any cookie, session, etc.  I'd be willing to use Firefox if such an extension exists on it as well.

Much appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at creating separate Chrome profiles? [Manage multiple users on Chrome](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2364824) Clicking the icon or using the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`M` switches profiles.

Comment: You could use different Windows accounts.  Possibly a little heavy-handed for what you're needing, but it was designed to do what you want for all programs.

Comment: Chrome does have profiles!  I never knew about this.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

*(Elaborating the solution provided in comments)*
[Profiles in Chrome](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2364824) is the thing you are looking for. This is how to use it,

### Add a new user

1. Click the **wrench icon**  on the browser toolbar.
2. Select **Settings**.
3. In the “**Users**” section, click **Add new user**.
4. Here, you can sign in to Chrome with a Google Account to associate the account with the user. Once signed in, all the bookmarks, apps, extensions, theme, and browser settings for the user will be synced to the account.

### Switch to another user

Click the icon on the top corner of the window or press `Ctrl+Shift+M` to select the user.